# Integrating a differential and notation of limits of integration

Tags: calculus, integration, notation

I am studying Thermodynamics and in class I came up with integrating the differential of internal energy:$$\int^2_1dU=U_2-U_1$$ But I don't understand why someone couldn't just write $$\int^2_1dU=U|^2_1=2-1=1$$ So how can we know if the integral mean the difference between two different function states?

Comment: $U_2$ needs not be equal to $2$, and likewise, $U_1$ needs not be equal to $1$.

Comment: There is an abuse of notation for the integral. The limits should be $U_1$ and $U_2$. What your integral means that it's integrating the internal energy between states "1" and "2", not between values $1$ and $2$

Comment: @Andrei Thanks for the answer. Our proffesor did that abuse yesterday.

Comment: You would evaluate it incorrectly. It’s an abuse of notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an abuse of notation. If $U$ is a function of $t$, say, then $dU=U'(t)\,dt$, the initial and final states are $U_1=U(1)$, $U_2=U(2)$. So what the integral is trying to mean is 
$$
\int_1^2\,dU=\int_1^2\,U'(t)\,dt=\left.U(t)\right|_1^2=U(2)-U(1). 
$$